# Moving content from one external storage location to a network with email confirmation

Tags: powershell

This is my first non-very-basic attempt at PowerShell scripting, so please excuse any poor etiquette.

I have an need to transfer approximately 30GB of video data from USB attached storage to a local network share. As I started this little project, I quickly identified that the processes I do naturally when performing this task need to be accounted for during the scripting, so my question is, how do I lay this all out and achieve my end goal of a simple copy and allow for this.

This is what I have thus far;

```
### (The purpose of this script is to automate the offloading of the Driver Cameras during FP1 and FP2 on a Friday. 
### Please remember that the cameras still need to be cleared after fireups on a Thursday"

Write-Host -NoNewLine "This script will move the footage captured on the SD cards of the FWD and RWD cameras and copy them to a defined network share" -ForegroundColor Green `n
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

# Execute the copy from the foward facing camera to the network and remove the local files once complete
Write-Host "FWD Camera copy in progress" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Magenta `n
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Get-ChildItem -Path "SourcePath" -Recurse |
  Move-Item -destination "DestinationPath" -Verbose

# Execute the copy from the rearward facing camera to the network and remove the local files once complete
Write-Host "RWD Camera copy in progress" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Magenta `n
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Get-ChildItem -Path "SourcePath" -Recurse |
  Move-Item -destination "DestinationPath" -Verbose


Write-Host "Sending email confirmation" -ForegroundColor Green `n
Send-MailMessage -smtpserver ServerIP -To "EmailAddress" -From "EmailAddress" -Subject "Camera offload" -body BodyHere -bodyasHTML
Write-Host "All tasks have completed" -ForegroundColor Green `n
Read-Host "Press any key to exit..."
exit
```

What I'd like to add is fault tolerance and allow for this to be communicated via email dynamically. find these criteria below;

1. There's a chance the cable connecting the storage to the machine running the script could become disconnected and only have moved a number of items, can I add something to aid this?
2. If a file transfer fails how do i restart and track this? Can I add a loop to confirm all the items have been moved?
3. How do I reference a fault code to dynamically update the content of the email sent to the end user?

Finally, are there any other common practice references I've missed and that need to be included?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you looked at [`robocopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) yet? It's a Microsoft provided tool and intended for complex copy operations. There's logging, error handling and more.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is a bit broad but let me try to address your question to help you to start. Of course I won't give you the whole code, just explanation what to use and why.

---

> There's a chance the cable connecting the storage to the machine running the script could become disconnected and only have moved a number of items, can I add something to aid this?

**First of all, as vonPryz said in comments, use [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)!**

It should survive network interruptions (e.g. check [this post](http://blog.gudge.com/2013/06/file-copy-over-windows-networks-with.html)). As a general approach, I'd first make sure that the content is successfully copied before deleting it. For example you could use something like this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse).FullName.Replace("C:\old\path","D:\new\path") | Test-Path
```

Of course the above will only check if file exists, not if the file has the same content. To compare if the files are the same you could use [`Get-FileHash`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-6).

> If a file transfer fails how do i restart and track this? Can I add a loop to confirm all the items have been moved?

Partially answered above. Robocopy has this feature built-in. And yes, you can add a loop to check.

> How do I reference a fault code to dynamically update the content of the email sent to the end user?

Check the example [from here](https://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/q-capturing-robocopy-error-codes-powershell):

```
robocopy b:\destinationdoesnotexist C:\documents /MIR

 if ($lastexitcode -eq 0)
 {
      write-host "Success"
 }
else
{
      write-host "Failure with exit code:" $lastexitcode
}
```

Also, there's [article on MS side listing all exit codes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/954404/return-codes-that-are-used-by-the-robocopy-utility-in-windows-server-2) which might be helpful to handle the exceptions. All you have to do is to add `$LASTEXITCODE` to email body.